# Is Thor forbidden by Asgardian law to kill anyone, or just other Asgardians?

Tags: marvel, thor-marvel

I've read that Thor (and other Asgardians) are forbidden to kill other Asgardians, under threat of being banished.

In S2: Ep12 of *Avengers Assemble*, Widow asks Thor to promise her that he will "take her out" if she falls under the spell of the infinity stones. Thor says:

*"It is forbidden by Odin's law, but I could attempt to banish you to the Dark Realm."*

I've never actually heard either way if there was an Asgardian law protecting mortals from being killed. The Wikipedia entries I've read mention the law forbids killing other Asgardians, and there is a comic (which I haven't read) where Thor himself is banished for killing another god. Is this law ever addressed regarding mortals / Midgardians though?

Comment: Maybe, it's worthy - unworthy thing all over again...

Comment: He doesn't seem to have any problem with killing Frost Giants, Dark Elves or Chitauri in the movies.

Comment: I don't have any citations for Asgardian law, but Thor as a character places great value on the other people who are his companions in battle. It may be that he's forbidden to strike down a comrade in arms, whether Asgardian or mortal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak to the standards set by cartoons and movies.  In the comics, however, Thor is bound by a code of chivalry not unlike a knight in ye days of olde.  His might is for the right, but enemies in fair combat take their chances (especially if the thunder god's temper boils over)

To illustrate this, four moments taken from Marvel Comics:

"Avengers" #98 (1972)
[image: "Avengers"]
"Thor" #194 (1971)
[image]

"Hulk" #300 (1984)
[image]

"Fantastic Four" #339 (1990) (Human Torch was possessed by a diabolical villain)[image]

Answer (score -1):

Remember the comics, animation, cinematic versions have the same baseline but have major differences. Yes it is true he can't or isn't allowed to in the comics and im guessing the animation follows along that route. The Thor in the mcu doesn't because such a law doesn't exist as a matter of a fact Thor is even quoted as telling loki that the earth is under his protection in the beginning of thor 2 
He traveled realm to realm fighting to undue the damage loki started.